# Auto deploy with Bitbucket

Tags: php, git, bitbucket, webhooks, ssh-keys

I was trying to auto deploy code on server but I am getting below error in webhook log:

> repository access denied. deployment key is not associated with the
>   requested repository. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I have already add my server public SSH key to the BitBucket and it's working fine if i run 'git pull' command in project directory.

I have set webhook as follow in BitBucket:

**URL:** http://IP-address/project-folder/hook/deploy.php

**Status:** Active (checked)

**SSL / TLS:** Skip certificate verification (checked)

**Triggers:** Repository push (selected)

deploy.php:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("git pull 2>&1");
```

After commit / push code locally I got above error in webhook log.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably because your php application is running under a different user that doesn't have necessary git/ssh environment variables/keys.

Comment: Try using the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` where you explicitly specify the key to use, should help with debugging.